# Skipping pages: Button should say "Install" instead of "Next"

Tags: nsis

I have an installer using the Modern UI 2 (MUI 2) that installs up to three components *into different locations*.

I use a `MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS` page and multiple `MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY` pages which are skipped automatically if the corresponding section is not selected (like described [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Skipping_Pages)).

So far so good.

However, if the last of the three components is not chosen to be installed, the button on the previous (not-skipped) directory page should say *Install* instead of *Next*, because next the last directory page will be skipped and the installation will be executed.

Since we already know which page will be skipped after we leave the components page, I wonder if there is a way to make it work?

Minimal example:

```
!include MUI2.nsh

InstallDir $EXEDIR
OutFile "skip.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel user
ShowInstDetails show

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE directoryPreA
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY 

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE directoryPreB
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY 

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section "A" SEC_A
  DetailPrint "Installing A..."
SectionEnd

Section /o "B" SEC_B
  DetailPrint "Installing B..."
SectionEnd

Function directoryPreA
  # Skips the directory page for A if not chosen for installation.
  ${Unless} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_A}
    Abort
  ${EndUnless}
FunctionEnd

Function directoryPreB
  # Skips the directory page for B if not chosen for installation.
  ${Unless} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_B}
    Abort
  ${EndUnless}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: So, I just found [this possible duplicate](/questions/13560602/change-the-text-of-the-button-from-next-to-install-after-accepting-license-agree), which is a small step in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Dir:A"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE directoryPreA
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY 

!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Dir:B"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE directoryPreB
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY 

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section "A" SEC_A
  DetailPrint "Installing A..."
SectionEnd

Section /o "B" SEC_B
  DetailPrint "Installing B..."
SectionEnd

Function .onSelChange
  GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
  ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_A}
  ${OrIf} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_B}
    SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(^NextBtn)"
  ${Else}
    SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(^InstallBtn)"
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function directoryPreA
  # Skips the directory page for A if not chosen for installation.
  ${IfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_A}
    Abort
  ${ElseIfNot} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_B}
    GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
    SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(^InstallBtn)"
  ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function directoryPreB
  # Skips the directory page for B if not chosen for installation.
  ${Unless} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC_B}
    Abort
  ${EndUnless}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: I didn't know you could `SendMessage` to the dialog elements in the `CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE` handlers. I was about to implement a `CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW` handler to try to do what you show here. Good to know.

Comment: @bassim You cannot do everything in PRE but the Next button is in the outer dialog and will exist no matter which page callback you are in. Controls that are in the inner dialog should for the most part be handled in the show callback.